# I cannot install alien | CentOS 8

Tags: centos, alien

I've a problem with my CentOS.

When I've tried to install [alien](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-aarch64/alien-8.95-3.el7.noarch.rpm.html) (el7 package, because el8 isn't available), I got this error (My CentOS has Polish language)

```
[mlodybukk@localhost Pobrane]$ sudo yum install alien
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Ostatnio sprawdzono ważność metadanych: 0:01:14 temu w dniu nie, 5 lip 2020, 22:45:38.
Błąd: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3) needed by alien-8.90-3.el7.nux.noarch
```

How can I repair this?

Comment: Polish is my native language. If i'll change language to English i won't understand some words :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling the Perl dnf module:

```
dnf module enable perl:5.26
```

And try installing alien again.

Comment: It doesn't work. :(

Comment: Alien gave the same error like before :(

Comment: The version for CentOS 7 won’t install on CentOS 8. You need to rebuild the package or find someone willing to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you, I've rebuilt that. Now it's working. You can write your comment as answer, I'll give you accepted answer. ;) Have a nice day!

Comment: @mlodybukk Hi! I'm faced with the same problem. Did you rebuild  alien? can you please tell me how you rebult it? (centos 8)

Answer (score 0):

I've enabled powertools and this fixed the issue on RockyLinux (Centos8)

```
dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```